# Are questions asking for literature recommendations on topic?

Tags: discussion

The title is most of the question, but I'm specifically wondering if it would be OK ask for literature recommendations on the relativistic rocket equation on the space exploration SE.  I can't find very many literature-recommendation questions, so I'm not sure if they're on topic at all, and I also realise that the RRE might itself be off-topic as it might live better in physics, although I think it is relevant to space exploration albeit in a slightly theoretical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best book ever about the relativistic rocket equation?" might be closed as asking for answers that are primarily opinion based, but if you give an example or two of the types of questions you are thinking about or somehow indicate the desired scope, and then ask for literature in which the answers are likely to be found I'm pretty sure it will be fine.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm not looking for a definitive book which I agree would be an opinion question: I'm just going through deriving it myself and want something which has the whole thing in one place, which I've not been able to find – although I should be competent to do it, I'm so rusty I make lots of mistakes without something to follow.